# .NET Identity: Generate token without explicit username / password

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a MVC application configured to use ASP.NET Identity.  More specifically, I've configured the application to use OAuth.  Everything is working perfectly as-is.  I can pass a username/password to my token endpoint and receive a token in return.  I have refresh tokens configured, I stripping default claims and adding my own, authorization attributes implemented, etc.

I have a new requirement to generate a token based on non- username / password combination.  The combination is similar to username/password at a high level: user passes two pieces of about themselves and, if true, a JWT is returned (just like with username/password).

Let's say I have a Person and AspNetUser table.  Some Person records will be AspNetUsers, but not all of them.  The ones that are not would like to authenticate using the method I described above.  I guess, technically they can be AspNetUser records but with no configured password and possibly email.

I'm having difficulty coming up with a proper solution to the problem.  Do I create a custom endpoint to take this alternative auth credentials and return a bearer token?  If so, any advice on the proper way to leverage .NET Identity to return the token?  Do I modify my custom OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to account for this alternate method?  If so, any advice on creating a "fake" (i.e. user does not exist in the AspNet* tables) identity to be return to the client?

As always, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just treat those two pieces of data as username  and password? Or  combine them and treat as password, with separate user name.

Comment: Two ways to login: username/password (stored in .NET identity provider) and [example, not actual implementation] firstname/lastname (stored in Person table).  I'm not particularly a fan of sending a request such as grant_type=password&username=[firstName]&password=[lastName].  I feel like that is a bit hacky.  I've gotten to the point where I making the evaluation if (again, example) first/last name are valid then proceed on.  Still not sure this is the best/preferred way of doing things.  Struggling with creating the properly Auth Ticket as I type this.

Comment: Did you solve your problem, @mtm927?

Comment: Yes - I ended up creating a custom class which represents an OAuth response.  Assuming the alternate credentials are valid, I'm manually creating an AuthenticationTicket, setting timeouts, then using the ApplicationJwtFormat class to protect the ticket.  This gives me the access token I was looking for.

Comment: @mtm927 Can you share your solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

@Zenichi requested how I solved this so I'm adding an answer.  Hindsight, there are probably better ways to solve this but this is what I landed on.

I added custom controller which returned responses similar to that of the Identity Framework.  I'm basically just building a ticket then creating an access token, then returning to the caller.  Here is a snippet:

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
{
"audience", string.Empty
}
});

var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties)
{
Properties =
{
IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Config.TokenLifeSpan)
};

var accessToken = new ApplicationJwtFormat(Config.Issuer).Protect(ticket);
var expiresIn = Config.TokenLifeSpan * 60 - 1;

var token = new OAuthSuccessResponse(accessToken, "bearer", Convert.ToInt32(expiresIn), null);
return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
```

---

```
    public OAuthSuccessResponse(string accessToken, string tokenType, int expiresIn, string refreshToken)
    {
        access_token = accessToken;
        token_type = tokenType;
        expires_in = expiresIn;
        refresh_token = refreshToken;
    }
```

---

In looking at it again, I'd probably would have (at least) pascal cased the property names of OAuthSuccessResponse and used the [JsonProperty] attribute to control casing during serialization.

Going further - I probably should have scrapped this approach and just continue to extend my OAuthProvider implementation to handle both traditional user/passwords and whatever other combination I needed.

Hope this helps.